# 2sxc : On Intranet Without Internet Connection

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

If you try to use 2sxc modul without internet connection (eg:protected intranet) there is a problem with tinyMCE editor loaded from CDN () by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to edit : /DesktopModules/ToSIC_SexyContent/dist/config/config.js

locate line :

```
config.Assets = "//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js\n" +
```

copy file from CDN to local site and change config.Assets line that point to this local file. eg:

```
config.Assets = "../edit/tinymce.min.js\n" +
```

then you can use this file behind strong firewall or on local development computer without internet access...

When you update 2sxc check and reapply files...